# short is closing long... and long is closing short i don't want it to

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using stratagey.order and close_entries_rule = 'ANY' to try and fix this but hasn't worked and I don't know what is causing this...

the long was closed by the short even tho it doesn't say it in the picture..
the short didnt show it closed even tho it did...

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
if bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value < bar_5m_prev_low// and barstate.isconfirmed// and ht_ema < (close / P_ema)
    if str.contains(orderIds, 'long') == false and array.get(openOrder1_long, 0) == 0
        mid_long_test = (bar_5m_prev_low + bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value) / 2
        if mid_long_test > (bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value * (min_dif_trade_small + 1))
            line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=mid_long_test, x2=bar_index+3, y2=mid_long_test, color = color.red, width = 2)
            SL_long = low / (1 + tp1_input_perc)
            array.set(L_SL_line, 0, SL_long)
            array.set(limitClose_long, 0, mid_long_test)
            array.set(limitEntry_long, 0, bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value / (1 + limitEntry_offset))
            line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=array.get(limitEntry_long, 0), x2=bar_index+3, y2=array.get(limitEntry_long, 0), color = color.rgb(21, 255, 0), width = 2)
            strategy.order(id = 'long', direction=strategy.long, limit = array.get(limitEntry_long, 0), stop = array.get(L_SL_line, 0))
            strategy.exit(id = 'C S long', from_entry='long', limit = array.get(limitClose_long, 0), stop = array.get(L_SL_line, 0))
            //L_s_count := L_s_count+1
            bear_imbalence_simple := low / 1.001
            array.set(openOrder1_long, 0, 1)

if str.contains(orderIds, 'long') == true
    array.set(openOrder1_long, 0, 0)
if bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value > array.get(limitClose_long, 0)
    if str.contains(orderIds, 'long') == false
        strategy.cancel('long')
        strategy.cancel('C S long')
        array.set(openOrder1_long, 0, 0)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//short
if bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value > bar_5m_prev_high // and barstate.isconfirmed// and ht_ema < (close / P_ema)
    if str.contains(orderIds, 'short') == false and array.get(openOrder1_short, 0) == 0
        mid_short_test = (bar_5m_prev_high + bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value) / 2
        if mid_short_test < (bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value / (min_dif_trade_small + 1))
            line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=mid_short_test, x2=bar_index+3, y2=mid_short_test, color = color.red, width = 2)
            SL_short = high * (1 + tp1_input_perc)
            array.set(S_SL_line, 0, SL_short)
            array.set(limitClose_short, 0, mid_short_test)
            array.set(limitEntry_short, 0, bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value * (1 + limitEntry_offset))
            line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=array.get(limitEntry_short, 0), x2=bar_index+3, y2=array.get(limitEntry_short, 0), color = color.rgb(21, 255, 0), width = 2)
            strategy.order(id = 'short', direction=strategy.short, limit = array.get(limitEntry_short, 0), stop = array.get(S_SL_line, 0))
            strategy.exit(id = 'C S short', from_entry= 'short', limit = array.get(limitClose_short, 0), stop = array.get(S_SL_line, 0))
            //L_s_count := L_s_count+1
            bull_imbalence_simple := low / 1.001
            array.set(openOrder1_short, 0, 1)

if str.contains(orderIds, 'short') == true
    array.set(openOrder1_short, 0, 0)
if bar_1s_prev_close_First_Value < array.get(limitClose_short, 0)
    if str.contains(orderIds, 'short') == false
        strategy.cancel('short')
        strategy.cancel('C S short')
        array.set(openOrder1_short, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pinescript, if your are in a long order and then send a short order, pinescript will automatically close your long order and place the short order.

It is explained here :

> strategy.entry() This command only places entry orders. It is affected
> by the pyramiding setting in the strategy’s properties and by the
> strategy.risk.allow_entry_in function. If there is an open market
> position when an opposite direction order is generated, the number of
> contracts/shares/lots/units will be increased by the number of
> currently open contracts (script equivalent: strategy.position_size +
> quantity). As a result, the size of the opened market position will be
> equal to the order size specified in the strategy.entry command.

See : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#order-placement-commands

So, you script behave correctly.

Comment: i am using strategy.order and strategy.exit.... not strategy.entry